# How to use jqueryui for right to left languages

Tags: css, jquery-ui, right-to-left

As I know, jQueryUI doesn't natively support RTL languages. Is there any official, or at least stable solution?

I do not need anything special. Just want to have clean right-to-left pages instead of normal left-to-right ones.

Comment: It's a bit outdated, but see if it helps you: https://github.com/OmarKhanfer/RTL-JQuery-UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://cssjanus.commoner.com/ to convert any LTR style to RTL. I used it to convert
jQuery UI style. It worked excellently.

Comment: For now I accept the answer till I test the new way, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work all the time, for ex. normally we have `left: 0px;` then it will convert it to `right: 0px;`, but we also need to reset the `left` position to `auto` as well, because there will be a conflict then. The converter also doesn't understand the `text-indent`property, for ex. when we have `text-indent: -99999px;` it will not convert it, but in rtl languages it should be `text-indent: 99999px;`, and many more ...